# nasm assembly language convert binary to decimal

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit

```
BinToDec:

    mov eax, msg8
    call sprint

    mov edx, 255
    mov ecx, sinput8
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 3
    int 80h

    mov eax,sinput8

    call atoiToDec
    call iprintLFToDec
    ret

;------------------------------------------
; void iprint(Integer number)
; Integer printing function (itoa)
iprintToDec:
    push    eax             ; preserve eax on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    ecx             ; preserve ecx on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    edx             ; preserve edx on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    esi             ; preserve esi on the stack to be restored after function runs
    mov     ecx, 0          ; counter of how many bytes we need to print in the end


divideLoopToDec:
    inc     ecx             ; count each byte to print - number of characters
    mov     edx, 0          ; empty edx
    mov     esi, 10         ; mov 10 into esi
    idiv    esi             ; divide eax by esi
    add     edx, 48         ; convert edx to it's ascii representation - edx holds the remainder after a divide instruction
    push    edx             ; push edx (string representation of an intger) onto the stack
    cmp     eax, 0          ; can the integer be divided anymore?
    jnz     divideLoopToDec ; jump if not zero to the label divideLoop

printLoopToDec:
    dec     ecx             ; count down each byte that we put on the stack
    mov     eax, esp        ; mov the stack pointer into eax for printing
    call    sprint          ; call our string print function
    pop     eax             ; remove last character from the stack to move esp forward
    cmp     ecx, 0          ; have we printed all bytes we pushed onto the stack?
    jnz     printLoopToDec  ; jump is not zero to the label printLoop

    pop     esi             ; restore esi from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    pop     edx             ; restore edx from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    pop     ecx             ; restore ecx from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    pop     eax             ; restore eax from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    ret

;------------------------------------------
; void iprintLF(Integer number)
; Integer printing function with linefeed (itoa) 
iprintLFToDec:
    call    iprintToDec     ; call our integer printing function

    push    eax             ; push eax onto the stack to preserve it while we use the eax register in this function
    mov     eax, 0Ah        ; move 0Ah into eax - 0Ah is the ascii character for a linefeed
    push    eax             ; push the linefeed onto the stack so we can get the address
    mov     eax, esp        ; move the address of the current stack pointer into eax for sprint
    call    sprint          ; call our sprint function
    pop     eax             ; remove our linefeed character from the stack
    pop     eax             ; restore the original value of eax before our function was called
    ret

;------------------------------------------
; int atoi(Integer number)
; Ascii to integer function (atoi)
atoiToDec:
    push    ebx             ; preserve ebx on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    ecx             ; preserve ecx on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    edx             ; preserve edx on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    esi             ; preserve esi on the stack to be restored after function runs
    mov     esi, eax        ; move pointer in eax into esi (our number to convert)
    mov     eax, 0          ; initialise eax with decimal value 0
    mov     ecx, 0          ; initialise ecx with decimal value 0

.multiplyLoopToDec:
    xor     ebx, ebx        ; resets both lower and uppper bytes of ebx to be 0
    mov     bl, [esi+ecx]   ; move a single byte into ebx register's lower half
    cmp     bl, 48          ; compare ebx register's lower half value against ascii value 48 (char value 0)
    jl      .finished       ; jump if less than to label finished
    cmp     bl, 49          ; compare ebx register's lower half value against ascii value 49 (char value 1)
    jg      .finished       ; jump if greater than to label finished
    cmp     bl, 10          ; compare ebx register's lower half value against ascii value 10 (linefeed character)
    je      .finished       ; jump if equal to label finished
    cmp     bl, 0           ; compare ebx register's lower half value against decimal value 0 (end of string)
    jz      .finished       ; jump if zero to label finished


    sub     bl, 48          ; convert ebx register's lower half to decimal representation of ascii value 
    add     eax, ebx        ; add ebx to our interger value in eax
    mov     ebx, 10         ; move decimal value 10 into ebx
    mul     ebx             ; multiply eax by ebx to get place value
    inc     ecx             ; increment ecx (our counter register)
    jmp     .multiplyLoopToDec ; continue multiply loop

.BinNum:
    sub bl, 48
    jmp BinLen

.finished:
    mov     ebx, 10         ; move decimal value 10 into ebx
    div     ebx             ; divide eax by value in ebx (in this case 10)
    pop     esi             ; restore esi from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    pop     edx             ; restore edx from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    pop     ecx             ; restore ecx from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    pop     ebx             ; restore ebx from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    ret

BinLen:
    mov     bl, [slen]
    mul     bl
    mov     bl, 2
```

I want to convert binary to decimal by using nasm assembly language. This is just one of the part of my code and the problem that I face is when I key in my input (binary) 1101 it just give me the output 1101 same as my input.

Comment: Your question is really difficult to read. Please use the 'code style' when you post code. Many Thanks

Comment: Your `atoi` function multiplies by 10 instead of 2... It's obvious that you are getting your binary number interpreted as if it was decimal...

Comment: BTW, don't put 48 and 49 in as magic numbers - nasm supports character literals - if you write `'0'` it will get expanded automatically to 48. Also, you don't need to explicitly compare against them, you can subtract `'0'` from your value and do an unsigned comparison against `1`, if it's above (`ja`) you have a value out of range (either negative, or greater than `1`). Otherwise, you can left shift the number read so far and `or` this new value in.

Comment: more optimizations possible: in `atoiToDec` don't use ecx as offset. instead of reading via `mov  bl, [esi+ecx]`, increasing ecx, you could read using `mov bl, [esi]`, and increase esi. ecx isn't needed then anymore at all